# SQLite support for windows phone 8 applications

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, nuget-package

I'have created windows phone 8 application 6 months back. **In that application I have used the SQLite database.** For this I've followed the below link.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18204.how-to-use-sqlite-with-a-windows-phone-8-application.aspx

Everything was fine. I have successfully stored and retrieved the data in the SQLite databse.

**Now suddenly the SQLite reference which I used is not working. To solve this I have removed the reference of SQLite from the project. I followed the same procedure which is mentioned in the above link. Now my solution contains 2 projects, one is Sqlite (which is c++ wrapper) and another one is SqliteDemo (Windows Phone Application).Everything is fine up to this. But when I try to build the application, then it is saying that All the projects with in the application must target the same platform.Use configuration manager to change the values.**

**I change the project platform to ARM and try to build the file. But the same error it is throwing.I change the project platform to X86 and try to build the file. But the same error it is showing. For reference please see the below image.**

[image]

Please help me how to solve the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about this, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sqlite-net

Comment: no please check the link whic I provided in the post

Comment: Please update your Visual studio...

Comment: Are you talking about "Sqlite-net-wp8" GitHub solution or "Sqlite-net" NuGet package?

Comment: have you updated your sqlite for windows phone?

Comment: no, I haven't updated my visual studio.

Comment: Are this http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cd120b42-30f4-446e-8287-45387a4f40b7 or this https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=system.data.sqlite what you're after?